# using an enviroment variable for local sequelize configuration

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, environment-variables, sequelize.js

I'm looking to use an environment variable inside of the config.json file of my project using sequelize. I'm using dotenv to set environment variables locally. My config.json file looks like this

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": process.env.DB_USER,
    "password": process.env.DB_PASS,
    "database": process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    "host": process.env.DB_HOST,
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "JAWSDB_URL",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that I can't use variables inside the config.json file. It looks like for production I can use the "use_env_varable" key and use the env variable for my connection string. So I guess I either need a way to figure out the combined connection string for my local mysql db or a way to use variables inside the config.json. Any solutions?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

you should change `config.json` file to a `config.js` module and make sure to `require` the `dotenv` at the very top.

```
require('dotenv').config(); // this is important!
module.exports = {
"development": {
    "username": process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    "host": process.env.DB_HOST,
    "dialect": "mysql"
},
"test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
},
"production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
}
};
```

NOTE: update your [`.sequelizerc`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#the--code--sequelizerc--code--file) file to match the new config file.

```
"config": path.resolve('./config', 'config.js'),
```

Comment: Just a hunch, follow the link above to see how to update your .sequelizerc file from their documentation [.sequelizerc docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#the--code--sequelizerc--code--file)

Comment: After struggling for an hour, then try googling and find your answer. My problem is solved. Thank you

Comment: How can i make it work with NextJS where I'm not able to use dotenv?

Comment: for new version of sequelize to import ```config.js``` move to ```models/index.js``` and change this line ```const config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];``` to ```const config = require("../config/config")[env];```

Answer (score 2):

I worked on this for quite a bit. I do not know why Sequelize does not use production when it is literally in the environment if you run `heroku run bash`. I was able to get it working by modifying the Sequelize object depending on the `JAWSDB_URL`, not the `NODE_ENV`.

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
let seq;

//express app configuration

if (process.env.JAWSDB_URL) {
    console.log("There is a JAWS DB URL")
    seq = new Sequelize(process.env.JAWSDB_URL)
}
else {
    seq = require("./models").sequelize
}
seq.sync().then(() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('server started on port ' + PORT));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a .sequelizerc file in the root directory.

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = { 
'config': path.resolve('server/config', 'config.js'),
'models-path': path.resolve('server/models'),
'seeders-path': path.resolve('server/seeders'),
'migrations-path': path.resolve('server/migrations')}
```

Then create config.js in config folder. Use following code in config.js

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "config.env" });

module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DBNAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    encrypt: process.env.DB_ENCRYPT,
    pool: {
      max: parseInt(process.env.DB_POOL_MAX),
      min: parseInt(process.env.DB_POOL_MIN),
      acquire: parseInt(process.env.DB_POOL_ACQUIRE),
      idle: parseInt(process.env.DB_POOL_IDLE),
    },
  },
```

After that run migration and seeders.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Passport, Sequelize, MySql:

On the index.js file setup through sequelize, look for this line:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
```

Try changing it to:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_DATABASE, process.env.DB_USERNAME, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, config);
```

Your .env should have:

```
DB_USERNAME:root (or whatever your username is)
DB_PASSWORD:NYB (whatever your password is)
DB_DATABASE:whatever_your_dbNameis_db
```

Last, depending on how your passport strategy is setup, look for something that says:

```
user.sequelize.sync().then(function(){
}...
```

You are going to need to place the: `database:process.env.DB_DATABASE`

```
user.sequelize.sync().then(function(){
     database:"process.env.dbn"
}...
```

This means that you should remove that key:value from the config.json.

It should be good to go and you will not have to convert anything.  Sequelize will take care of all of that.

Comment: One thing I forgot to add is you may have to drop(reset) your database/table in order to for this work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my config.js file looks like:

```
const fs = require('fs');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  "development": {
    "username": process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    "host": process.env.DB_HOST,
    "dialect": process.env.DB_CONNECTION
  },
  "test": {
    "username": process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    "host": process.env.DB_HOST,
    "dialect": process.env.DB_CONNECTION
  },
  "production": {
    "username": process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    "host": process.env.DB_HOST,
    "dialect": process.env.DB_CONNECTION
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the use_env_variable for development too. you already seem to be using dotenv, so im assuming you have a .env file already setup. just add this line to it:

LOCALDB=mysql://[user]:[pass]@[sqldomain]/[db name]

replace the stuff in [] as necessary, and in your config file set "use_env_variable" to LOCALDB, just like how you have JAWSDB for production.