# Error when trying to use environment variables with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, environment-variables, sequelize.js

I've been following the sequelize documentation on implementing and reading from .env files, but I'm still met with an access denied error. I have created the config.js file and set up the .sequelizerc to read from config.js instead of config.json. When I tested using hardcoded data for password and database in config.js everything worked. When I tried using environment variables as intended I get thrown the access denied error. The values in the .env file in the screenshot are obviously not the ones I use.

This is my setup:

[image: project_structure]

[image: index.js]

[image: config.js]

[image: .sequelizerc]

[image: .env]

[image: error]

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to load the dotenv module to use an .env file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38757728)

Comment: Thank you. I needed to add the require('dotenv').config() at the start of the config.js file as described, but I also had to move the .env file from the config folder to the root of the project for it to work properly. I'm guessing that's where process.env expects it to be? Also, is there an implementation for using cmd-env instead of dotenv?

Comment: Not sure about that. Normally `process.env` refers to the *actual* environment variables, which exist in the shell (the terminal) that started the node.js process. For instance, `process.env.USER` is your user name. That dotenv module sort of ‘fakes’ them, or adds environment variables from a file.