# why sequelize taking postgres as a dbname instead of which i am passing in .env file?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to **migrate my existing migration file to my new Database.** But whenever I execute the migration command, the **migration is done on the Postgres database**, not in which database name I passed in the .env file.

can anyone please explain to me why Sequelize select the Postgres database name? Is this Sequelize's default behavior to select Postgres as the default database name when Sequelize didn't get the database name?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using an enviroment variable for local sequelize configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757728/using-an-enviroment-variable-for-local-sequelize-configuration) Also, [doc](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#configuration).